# The CSS from my email templates does not work on yahoo email

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, email-templates

I have built a few email templates the issue is that the CSS is not working on yahoo / outlook / windows native app etc. Pretty much anything that is not mac or google.

I did write the templates using tables but for the CSS I used the style tag because I want the templates to also be responsive.

I will leave some code examples below maybe you can point out my mistake.

```
 <style type="text/css" data-hse-inline-css="true">
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      body {
        background-color: #ebeff5;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
      }

      table,
      tr,
      td {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      table {
        border-spacing: 0;
      }

      img {
        width: 100%;
        border: 0;
      }

      p {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #39506f;
        line-height: 30px;
      }

      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
        background-color: #ebeff5;
      }

      .main {
        background-color: #ebeff5;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 750px;
        padding: 35px 15px;
      }

      .spacing-one {
        height: 15px;
      }

      .spacing-two {
        height: 25px;
      }

      .card {
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }

      .main-font {
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #1b3040;
        font-weight: 400;
      }
...
```

```
    <main class="wrapper">
      <table class="main">
        <tr>
          <td class="card">
            <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img
                    class="logo"
                    src="path"
                    alt="logo"
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="spacing-two"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <h1 class="main-font">Hey {{name}},</h1>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="spacing-one"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>text.</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="spacing-one"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="height: 56px">
                  <a href="{{url}}" target="_blank">
                    <span class="main-button"
                      >Reset Password
                      <img
                        class="main-button-icon"
                        src="path"
                        alt=""
                    /></span>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="spacing-one"></tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>
                    text.
                  </p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest issue here is that not all email clients support HTML5 semantics (like the `<main>` tag you're using). And email clients will behave very differently in how they do not support it. You can refer to Can I email for details on [support of HTML5 semantics](https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-semantics/).

For example, Gmail does not support the `<main>` tag. But it will change it into a `<div>` element and apply the same `class` attribute you had in the first place, making this seamless.

Yahoo, however, will remove the `<main>` element completely, thus also removing the styles you wanted to apply on it.

In your case, changing `<main class="wrapper">` into `<div class="wrapper">` is enough to make it work in Yahoo.

This might not be enough for Outlook on Windows and Windows native client as both of those use Word as a rendering engine and have very poor support for CSS. Thinks like `margin:0 auto` or `max-width` won’t work. You will have to rely on conditional comments, tables and eventually `mso` specific styles to get a proper rendering for Outlook on Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much! I make the changes you suggested and I will test them. Do you know is the <center> tag will work?

Comment: It works in Outlook on Windows. But might still need to set a fixed `width` on your `<table>` (otherwise content will take all the window’s width).

Comment: I have tested it and it doesn't work on yahoo. Div has a really low % when searching in CanIEmail but I will be using it to see if it will work.

Comment: Hello, I have just made the changes that you suggested and some others. I have tested it on yahoo and it still not working.

Comment: @Oliver Can you share the entire HTML code that you are sending? Also, what service are you using to send your email?

Comment: Sure, here is a codepen https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/pen/poZPQpP?editors=1000. I have made some changes and it seems to work fine on yahoo desktop devices but it's still not working on mobile. The service that I use is AWS SES

Comment: The main problem I see is that Yahoo (desktop webmail) doesn’t support the `class` attribute on `<img>` element. So it's safer to wrap your logo image in a `<span class="logo">` and use `.logo img {}` as a selector. Also, Yahoo doesn't support transparent hexadecimal colors, so be sure to only use 3 or 6 hex long colors. On mobile, Yahoo on Android requires an empty `<head></head>` first before your real `<head>`.

Comment: The empty head tag work!! Thank you very much! Do you know of any apps or websites that are free where I can test my emails? I found a few but they don't seem to be very accurate.